# Unable to access agent settings to publish

Tags: dialogflow-es

Accessing Dialogflow "https://dialogflow.cloud.google.com", I can work on my agent as expected. However, I cannot click on the gear icon to access settings like publishing. (img below)

When i select the drop down menu, it endlesly indicates "loading agents..."

I have tried with chrome, firefox, and safari, made sure that cookies are not being blocked.

Checking on chrome's devtools, i see the following error for one of the calls

https://dialogflow.clients6.google.com/v2beta1/projects/-/locations/global/agent:search?requestSource=DIALOGFLOW_CONSOLE&pageToken&pageSize=1000&key=(mykey)

```
{
  "error": {
    "code": 503,
    "message": "The service is currently unavailable.",
    "status": "UNAVAILABLE"
  }
}
```

[Non active gear](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5Txon.png)

Answer (score 0):

I just found the URL for the settings page. It is not a solution but a work-around.

The format is as follows:
https://dialogflow.cloud.google.com/#/editAgent/**yourAgentName**/languages